# Stubbing connect middleware

Tags: javascript, express, sinon, node.js-connect

I have a middleware (coffeescript):

```
 basic = (req, res, next) ->
    return next() if not app.settings.auth?
    express.basicAuth(app.settings.auth.username, app.settings.auth.password) req, res, next
```

How can i stub the basicAuth function to control the flow?

I have tried:

```
express = require 'express'
sinon.stub express, 'basicAuth'
```

and get error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot set property basicAuth of function createApplication() {
  var app = connect();
  utils.merge(app, proto);
  app.request = { __proto__: req };
  app.response = { __proto__: res };
  app.init();
  return app;
} which has only a getter
```

I have also tried:

```
connect = require 'connect'
sinon.stub connect, 'basicAuth'
```

which errors because connect isnt a directly available dependency of my app (express requires it)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own modules, which exports the methods you wish to stub.

```
# stub.coffee
express = require 'express'

# export basicAuth as a stub-friendly export
module.exports.basicAuth = express.basicAuth
```

You would require this instead of or in addition to express.

```
stubpress = require 'stubbableExpress'

basic = (req, res, next) ->
  return next() if not app.settings.auth?
  stubpress.basicAuth(app.settings.auth.username, app.settings.auth.password) req, res, next
```

And that gives you something you can stub:

```
stubpress = require 'stubbableExpress'
sinon.stub(stubpress, 'basicAuth')
```